# Error al instalar optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin. Code: EACCES, errno: -13, syscall: rename

Tags: npm, webpack

CONTEXTO: En un curso estoy tratando de instalar [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) para **mandar mis archivos a producción**. Lo que se busca hacer es **minimizar el código sass**. En el curso se usa es [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) pero debido a que está "deprecated" hay que usar la primera.

PROBLEMA: Pero en la dcumentación el mini-css dicen que hay que **usar otra librería para eso**: [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin) pero cuando lo voy a instalar me sale lo siguiente

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/css-tree/node_modules/source-map
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/css-tree/node_modules/source-map' -> '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/source-map'
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/action/move.js:86:7
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:11:16
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/rename.js:11:14
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/css-tree/node_modules/source-map' -> '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/source-map'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/css-tree/node_modules/source-map' -> '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/source-map'
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/action/move.js:86:7
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:11:16
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/rename.js:11:14
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/css-tree/node_modules/source-map' -> '/mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/source-map' parent: 'cssnano' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/users/usuario/documents/Coursers/Codigo_Facilito/Practica-Web_avanzado/Project/Stories/npm-debug.log
```

No tengo linux, sino ubuntu 18.04 LTS en Windows 10. En este he intentado instalar esto con `sudo npm install [dependencia]`. He intentado hacerlo con CMD como administrador y nada. No sé qué debo hacer para resolver esto. Y depaso las soluciones que encuentro son para cuando hay que intalar algo pero de forma global.

¿Cómo puedo resolver esto o al menos encontrar una alternativa para lo que quiero hacer? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

### - SOLUCIÓN DUDOSA:

Después de investigar como 3 horas para resolver este problema -*sí lo solcucioné*- pero no estoy seguro exactamente cómo.

#### ¿Qué hice?

Al parecer el npm instalado en ubuntu no es el mismo que instalas por cmd. Creo que influyó que al intalar por primera vez npm y nodejs lo hice por estos dos canales. Pero no estoy seguro

Basicamente lo que hice fue **actualizar mi npm por línea de comando** (ubuntu) con el siguiente comando:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

No sé si influyó pero **al usar ubuntu lo hice como administrador**. Osea, hice click en donde te dice "run as administrator".

Aunque no sé si funcionó porque al intentar meterme en `./node_modules/normalize-url` y hacer `ls` no me dejaba ver nada.

En fin. Continuando, **después de la instalación ejecuté** `sudo npm cache clean --force`. Supe que funcionó porque, en comparación con la primera vez que la usé (en ubuntu) **no me salió la barra de prograso**. Esta vez sí.

Y ahora es que pude ejecutar el comando que realmente necesitaba: `sudo npm install --save-dev optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`

### TOMAR EN CUENTA:

**Esto no es seguro**. Hice muchas cosas tanto en cmd como en ubuntu:

- **Desinstalar node y reinstalar con su última versión** (cmd)
- **Hacer justo lo que expliqué pero en cmd** (no funcionó, no sé por qué)
- **Borrar `/Usuario/AppData/Roaming/npm` y `/Roaming/npm-cache` antes de hacer lo primero de la lista**

Y otras cosas que ya no recuerdo bien. Así que no es que recomiendo mucho esto. Pueden probarlo y si no funciona investigar.